# Jenkins not able to execute Browserstacklocal binary and hangs

Tags: windows, jenkins, browserstack

I am trying to run a selenium test through Jenkins with browser Stack
If I run the test on Jenkin windows server command line, it works perfectly, but upon running on jenins it hangs.

below is the stack trace.

Connecting local

```
Error while trying to execute binary { [Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.browserstack\BrowserStackLocal.exe --daemon start --log-file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\testing-QA_LiveChat_Automation\local.log" --key qqFh7bzuqV587hBjFdKs

  at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
  at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
]
  killed: false,
  code: 4294967295,
  signal: null,
  cmd:
   'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\.browserstack\\BrowserStackLocal.exe --daemon start --log-file "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\testing-QA_LiveChat_Automation\\local.log" --key qqFh7bzuqV587hBjFdKs' }
Retrying Binary Download. Retries Left 5
```

Comment: Are you passing the --log-file parameter ? If yes can you remove it and try again ?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this? I'm experiencing the same error.